# Server Receive empty JSON string array From android app

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

I am sending image data from my android app to server,I can see in log that string array is not empty and has correct data but on server it receive null.

Here is my AsyncTask from where i am sending data to server

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        BufferedReader reader;

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/Data/galleryLog.php");

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            Log.d(TAG,"String Data "+Images);

            //For POST Only - Begin
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(Images);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            connection.connect();
            //For POST Only End
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(TAG, "POST RESPONSE CODE " + responseCode);
            String LoginResult;
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                //Success
                Log.d(TAG, "Success connection with database");
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                reader.close();

                Log.d(TAG, "Reader Close - Printing Result ");
                //Print Result
                Log.d(TAG, "Calling Response " + response.toString());
            }


            return null;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the string i got in logcat which is not empty and has correct data

```
String Data {"galleryDesc":"My First Gallery","images":[{"base64code":"Base64Image","type":"jpg","imagename":"image-101.jpg"}],"User_ID":"18","galleryTitle":"Image-101.jpg"}
```

My Php Code where i am printing received data into file but it give me blank file always

```
<?php
$tm = 'ritu_gallery_'.time().'.log';
file_put_contents($tm, print_r($_POST, TRUE));

echo "Response<br>";
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Its create text file like that

> Array ( )

**UPDATE:** its an issue in AsyncTask String array. I don't know why its not working.If anyone knows please let me know

When i am sending this string array to server.it's print blank values on server

```
 {"galleryDesc":"My First Gallery","images":[{"base64code":"Base64Image","type":"jpg","imagename":"image-101.jpg"}],"User_ID":"18","galleryTitle":"Image-101.jpg"}
```

when i add above String array into this

```
String data= URLEncoder.encode("Pic","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(Images,"UTF-8");
```

It creates file on server like this

> Array (
>       [Pics] => {"galleryDesc":"My First Gallery","images":[{"base64code":"Base64Image","type":"jpg","imagename":"101.jpg"}],"User_ID":"18","galleryTitle":"101.jpg"}
>   )

with all correct values.If anyone know why this is happening. Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing the wrong variable here, an image is a file and it will be in `$_FILE` variable not in $_POST variable, also the form should be multipart formdata, i don't know if you are doing that or not cause i don't know very much about android but if are doing so then you can see your file in $_FILE variable

Comment: can you please tell me how to view file in php cuz i am not good in php

Comment: just like you do it in post and sorry it is $_FILES. $_FILES['images']

Comment: actually i copied php code from some website.So i can't make changes as you saying

Comment: you just have to access the image from $_FILES['images'] and you can access rest of the data by $_POST as you were doing this previously. and here is a link if you need further documentation https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: i want to print complete string array in text file.Please tell me how it can be done cuz i am doing mistakes in what you suggested

Comment: if you show me what are you doing then i can help and you want to print the image as string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141789/discussion-between-adam-and-ritu).

Comment: @adam as you can see image is base64 not as file so it can consider as string making $_File wont help.It must be app side issue

Comment: yeah that's what we finally found out that it was an app side issue

Comment: yes this is happening causing in the second way you are encoding the data in utf-8 format which is required by php

Comment: @adam no actually if i do like this `String data= URLEncoder.encode(Images,"UTF-8");` then it doesn't send anything on server. So why its happening if i adding a key to it?

Comment: actually it should receive when encoding is defined and it is utf-8,i checked my android app and they are using volley as i said before so on the problem is still in the android front, you didn't try volley?

Comment: Yes i did but not as i want i wanted to send JSON string without doing any UTF conversion.So for now its working but not as i want

Comment: @Ritu you have to send the data using utf-8 encoding, anyways i hope i helped a little.

Comment: Whats the difference between
`String data= URLEncoder.encode("Pic","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(Images,"UTF-8");`
`String data= URLEncoder.encode(Images,"UTF-8");` 
What's the difference between both cuz both doing UTF encoding but one send data other don't

Comment: in one there is a key, in the other there is just the image